# How do I keep a menu item group open when rotating android device

Tags: android, menu, rotation, android-configchanges

I've handled screen rotation config changes in the android manifest, which works for dialog themed activities, however for these menu groups, which open after selecting a menu item (in onOptionsItemSelected) still close when I rotate the screen. Can I handle these in onConfigurationChanged? Or is there a better way? I've attached the code that opens the submenu.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.submenu) {
      if (item.getItemId() == this.submenu) {
         return true;
      }
      this.value = item.getItemId();
      item.setChecked(true);
      //do something with value
      return true;
   }
   //...
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a very simple fix. I needed to add the line `android:configChanges="orientation"` to my activity in the AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 3):

you will need to override

```
    @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
```

But to do this you must specify the configuration change you will handle yourself by adding to the manifest file on the Activity level the tag

```
     android:configChanges=["mcc", "mnc", "locale",
                             "touchscreen", "keyboard", "keyboardHidden",
                             "navigation", "orientation", "screenLayout",
                             "fontScale", "uiMode"]
```

on onConfigurationChanged save the state and reload it on onResume

Comment: Hazem, Thanks for your response. I have this variable in my manifest file (and I override onConfigurationChanged), and it handles orientation and keyboard changes successfully: `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"`. Unfortunately, this still causes the group to close. Is there an activity configChanges variable that will keep this menu item open?